# Adding content in a div using php ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, dynamic, custom-post-type

I'm having issues.  Once a image is clicked I need to add a div below it and this div needs to contain content from the link associated with this image.  If are confused look at this link http://grovemade.com/
I need functionality similar to their Our Team section.  I've tried various resources and none have been much help.  If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this,

```
$(document).on('click','yourButton',function() {
    $("YOURDIV").load(url, { somedataforphp : somedataforphp }, 
    function(responseTxt) {
       // maybe a callback? or maybe appand responseTxt into the div under the image
    });
});
```